# Is it possible to integrate Apache Lenya with JForum (or JavaBB)?

Tags: java, content-management-system, forum

I'd like to install both applicatios and make them share the same users database (and HTTP sesion of course - sho that whoever logs in to lenya is logged into the forum as well).

Is it possibe in configuration or do I have to modify sources of both Lenya and forum software ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're certainly going to have to modify the Lenya source. Lenya uses XML files for users and passwords. You may be able to modify Lenya's authentication code to hit up whatever user DB / sessions exist in JForum.

Or you could go with CAS, OpenID, or Shibboleth. Still would require editing code, but it might be easier if you have the infrastructure for one of those systems.